# Python Copy a Picture between a Raspberry Pi and a Windows File server

Tags: python, server, copy, raspberry-pi4, smb

I want to copy the image Test.png (→ path: /home/testuser/Desktop/Picture.png) to my file server (→ Path: \Server/ImagesBackup/). For this, I tried the following:

```
pathpicture=r"\\Server/backup/Bild1.png"
path= "/home/testuser/Pictures/Picture.png"
smbclient.copyfile(path,pathpicture, username=username, password=password)
```

Unfortunately, I only get the following error message:

**ValueError: src must be an absolute path to where the file should be copied from.**

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to copy a file using the solution provided here:
[stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442922/smbclient-python-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-valueerror-src-must-be-an-absolute-path-to-where-the-fi)

```
from smbclient import shutil as smb_shutil

pass_user = 'user'
server = 'address'

smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)

smb_shutil.copyfile(
    r"C:\\test.png", rf"\\{server}\\scaner\\test.png", 
    username=pass_user, password=pass_user
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes in windows. It is also asking for an absolute path

That complies with this>  C:\SomeDirectory\Image.jpg

Comment: I know, but  "/home/testuser/Pictures/Picture.png" is an absolute Path or not?

Answer (score 0):

smbclient.copyfile is used only to copy a file to a different location on the same server. This will fail if the src and dst paths are on different servers.

I have not found a way to copy it so what i ended up doing is to create a new file and write to it.

```
with smbclient.open_file(destination, "w") as fd:
    df.to_csv(fd)
```